# Dynamically Change X-Axis using DAX | Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I wanted a customizable visual of a bar chart or line chart that allows plotting the chart weekly, monthly, quarterly, or annually. Unfortunately, no custom visualizations are available (as far as I can tell from my search), and Power BI does not give us any substitute visuals.

The requirement was something like this:

[image: Image of dynamic x-axis]

I tried various ways to get the type of chart I wanted, but nothing worked. Then I came across this alternative to the drill drown feature of charts for customised axis scales by [Inkey Solutions](https://www.inkeysolutions.com/blogs/power-bi-dynamic-scales-values/) but still, there were some limitations to it.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by using bookmark. Stack Visuals one on top of another with the desired X Axis and then use bookmark [How To](https://radacad.com/bookmarks-and-buttons-making-power-bi-charts-even-more-interactive)